# How to keep on scrolling the page vertically and adding items continuously?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've a huge data to display on my page.I want to do this in a similar manner as it is done on facebook page,i.e. I will scroll down the vertical bar and items will be added.I got one web link for this and used its code as follows:--

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Form1.aspx.cs"         Inherits="Form1" %>

    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
        string _cmdText = "SELECT TOP 20 TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID, Convert(CHAR(10),TRIAL_ACTIVATE_DATE,103) as 'ACTIVATEDATE',TRIAL_CD_SERIAL_NO FROM TDSMAN_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmdText, conn);
        da.Fill(ds,  "User_Detail");
        tblUserDetail.DataSource = ds;
        tblUserDetail.DataBind();
    }
}  
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Dynamic Content Load on Scroll</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #666666;
    }
    .divLeft
    {
        height: 220px;
        border: solid 1px blue;
        width: 300px;
        text-align: left;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .divProgress
    {
        width: 15%;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    .tblHeader
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: blue;
        color: red;
    }
    td 
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //following code utilizes jQuery 1.2.6
    var prev = 0;
    $(document).ready(

    //DIV showing the message "Loading..." is hidden initially
    //The message will be shown when records are fetched with AJAX 
    //when user has scrolled to the bottom of the DIV scrollbar 
    function () {
        $(".divProgress").hide();

        $(".divLeft").scroll(

    function () {
        //triggering point is when the difference of the heights of the TABLE 
        //and DIV match the DIV's scrollTop value
        if ($("#tblUserDetail").height() - this.scrollTop == $(this).height()) {
            //progress bar         
            $(".divProgress").ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
            $(".divProgress").ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });

            //get last Order Id to track next fetch
            var OrderIdLast = $("#tblUserDetail tr:last").children("td:first").html();

            //get last table row in order to append the new result set increment
            var trLast = $("#tblUserDetail tr:last");
            if (parseInt(OrderIdLast, 10) > parseInt(prev, 10)) {
                prev = OrderIdLast;
                //make a async call to fetch the incremental results     
                $.post("AsyncHandler.ashx?lastOrderId=" + OrderIdLast, function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        //append new result set to last row
                        trLast.after(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h3>This  is a demo to show Continous Scrolling</h3>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="divLeft">
            <asp:GridView ID="tblUserDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="2" Width="100%">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblHeader" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Detail Id">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                              <%#Eval("TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activate Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("ActivateDate")%>
                            <input type="hidden" id="htxtOrderId" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CD Serial No.">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("TRIAL_CD_SERIAL_NO")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <div  class="divProgress">
            Loading....
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've introduced a handler and its code goes as follows:--

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="AsyncHandler" %>

    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

   public class AsyncHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        //REMOVE BELOW LINE if you are using it in a real application
        //It is here to simulate the delay while fetching results 
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        //The last OrderId is used to get the next increment
        int lastOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["lastOrderId"]);

        //The PrepareDataSet method stuffs the DataSet into a HTML table
        context.Response.Write(PrepareDataSet(lastOrderId));
    }

    private string PrepareDataSet(int LAST_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
        string _cmdText = "Select TOP 10 TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID,Convert(Varchar,TRIAL_ACTIVATE_DATE,103) ActivateDate,TRIAL_CD_SERIAL_NO From TDSMAN_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL Where TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID >" + LAST_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(_cmdText, conn);
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,  "User_Detail");

        //The BuildRows method prepares a HTML table & stuffs the resultset into it
        return BuildRows(ds.Tables[0]);
    }

    private string BuildRows(System.Data.DataTable dt)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.Data.DataRow dr;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr class='tblRow'>");
                dr = dt.Rows[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>" + dr[j] + "</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    }
```

Now when I run the code a grid is shown on my page with data in it.But when I scroll down,neither "Loading.." is shown nor next batch of data is populated in the grid.Do any of you have any idea,how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when scroll down to get more result you have to get data from database and merge it with the current data in the datasource of gridview like the following.

```
private string PrepareDataSet(int LAST_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
        string _cmdText = "Select TOP 10 TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID,Convert(Varchar,TRIAL_ACTIVATE_DATE,103) ActivateDate,TRIAL_CD_SERIAL_NO From TDSMAN_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL Where TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID >" + LAST_TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(_cmdText, conn);
        DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds,  "User_Detail");

        //get the previous data from chche
        var parentDt = (DataSet)_cache["key For previous data in cache"];
        ds.Merge(parentDt);  
        tblUserDetail.DataSource = ds;
        tblUserDetail.DataBind();  

        //this when this function is in the page 
        //but if the function is in the handler you can return dataset to the page and //bind it to the tblUserDetail GridView like above

        //Notes:
        //-you don't need to build rows you just bind the new ds to the gridview.
        //-when you get the first data on page load save the data into the cache or 
        //any state management variables.
    }
```

i hope this could help :)

Comment: @Paesmaker,The function is written in the handler(as I mentioned in my code above).When I'm copying your edited code,it's giving error as "The name _cache doesn't exist in the current context",also error for gridview id,tblUserDetail.What is "key for previous data in cache"?The "TRIAL_USER_DETAIL_ID"?